# Registering attendance by day

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to create an attendance system using PHP MySQL and even a little jQuery. The specification I have in mind is to have all my members echoed in one table row and in the rest I would like to have an infinite array of dates but showing month by month.

I just wanted to know how I could get the days of the month into this table dynamically? 
Does anyone have any working examples or point me into the right direction?

I have a mini layout which goes like so or view my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSsKg/):

```
<form action='this_page.php' method='post'>
<table>
<th>Member</th>
<th>Day One</th>
<th>Day Two</th>
<tr>
    <td>Memeber One</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='1' /></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='1' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Member Two</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='1' /></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='student[davidsmith]' value='1' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you want, but to get the days of a month, you can use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

e.g.

```
$startDate = new DateTime(); //today
$endDate = new DateTime('2013-12-31');

 for ($c = $startDate; $c <= $endDate; $c->modify('+1 day')) {
       echo $c->format('d');
 }
```

will print the days from today to the rest of the year, use `->format('N')` to get the month name. [check here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for other params accepted by `format()`

Comment: thanks that helps get me started along with the PHP DateTime reference!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this manual work and also it will make you confuse, instead you can you below application which is opensource and its free as well:

[Please try this application](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=121561&package_id=132628)